# How to remove duplicates while exporting from different excel files to database

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I want to export data from different excel files to database , 
while exporting if the database table already contains the same row data present in the excel then that row should not be loaded to database.

can anybody provide me the code.

I know already how to export from excel to database, with this if am exporting same data to database then am seeing two rows with same data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to import data to a staging table and add non duplicates to the main table using

```
insert into tartget_table(col_list)
select t1.col_list from staging as t1 where not exists
(select * from target_table as t2 where t1.keycol=t2.keycol)
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to export the data of excel to a temp table and then using distinct or any other select only distinct rows and insert then to your own tables